# How to check for working copy in tortoise svn

Tags: tortoisesvn

I am confused in switching  from trunk to branch .How to check for my current working copy in svn during switching

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite understand what you're asking. Are you wanting to know whether a file in your working copy is from the trunk or a branch?

Answer (score 1):

Using TortoiseSVN, you can see in the file properties whereabouts you are in the repository. If you right-click on the file, select Properties then look at the Subversion tab, the first entry will be URL. This will be displayed something like:

```
path_to_repository/trunk/filename
```

or

```
path_to_repository/branches/branch_name/filename
```

The URL is what would be updated if you were to commit that file. In the first example, you would be working in the trunk, in the second example, you would be in a branch.

Comment: I have downloaded fresh code from  repository which contain 'trunk','branch' and 'tag' and I want to work in branch .Is switching necessary in this case ?

Comment: I understand now. Normally you only want to check-out the trunk, a branch or a tag (i.e. a level lower down that what you've checked out). You then use "switch" to change what's in your working copy (i.e. if you'd checked out the trunk, you might switch to a branch). That way, your working copy (what you have on your computer) only has one instance - checking out the higher level (like you have) would mean you'd have the trunk as well as *every* branch and tag!

Answer (score 0):

If your question can be decrypted as

"I want to know, to which part of repository linked my WC at the time"

you have to use `svn info` command, URL parameter

```
>svn info
...
URL: http://mayorat.ursinecorner.ru:8088/svn/Hello/trunk
...
```

Comment: I have downloaded fresh code from repository which contain 'trunk','branch' and 'tag' and I want to work in branch .Is switching necessary in this case ?

Comment: @user1938168 - no. You can just `cd` to needed folder **inside common WC**. But better choice may be re-checkout only trunk and needed branch into separate WC