# TortoiseSVN equivalent to "svn info"

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'd like to find an equivalent of the "svn info" command in Tortoise SVN.

This is the command that shows your parent URL (so I can figure out what branch I'm under), and the latest revision you are on.

Comment: While not using the same terminology, they have the same answer: [Can I see the currently checked out revision number in Tortoise SVN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89741/can-i-see-the-currently-checked-out-revision-number-in-tortoise-svn/89811#89811) and [How to check for working copy in tortoise svn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15077604/how-to-check-for-working-copy-in-tortoise-svn/15078815#15078815)

Comment: @crashmstr thanks. i decided to ask and answer the question here because i couldn't find anything on SO with google. and the answer seemed rather unintuitive. i think having "svn info" in the title is important for findability

Comment: I 've just came from google looking for "svn info" for tortoise so this answer is really helpful and easily discoverable.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When right-clicking on the folder, instead of going under the "TortoiseSVN" context menu, go to the "Properties" menu item. That's the actual *Windows* property dialog, not the "Properties" link in the TortoiseSVN submenu.

In the windows folder properties dialog, you will see a "Subversion" tab.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of properties]

Comment: That's very counter-intuitive! Why Tortoise does not provide a menu for that?

Comment: Also, I'd like to have a command-line based query for the meta data in order to iterate over multiple directories.

Comment: @t3az0r You can use `svn info` for that- http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.info.html

Comment: @Kip What would be the equivalent to `svn info` on windows client "TortoiseSVN"? Can you offer an example, please?

Comment: @t3az0r when you install TortoiseSVN, there is an option to add svn command line tools, and an option to add them to windows PATH. If you enable both options, then you can run `svn` commands (such as `svn info`) from the command line.

Comment: The Subversion tab in Properties is not an equivalent fpr `svn info`. With `svn info [filename]` you will get info on locks. The tab does not show a lock owner, _even if the file is locked_. At least not with Tortoise v1.10.

Comment: @Würgspaß sounds like a bug, given that there are fields for lock owner and lock creation date. I'd suggest reporting to TortoiseSVN team. I've never worked with locks so I don't know much about this.

Comment: @Kip I'm not sure, accoring to the docs, checking the lock status should be done like this: "Check for Modifications..." -> "Check Repository". And this seems to work fine. Cf. https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-locking.html#tsvn-dug-locking-status. I use the command line anyway, but others in our project use tortoise and asked me about it.